# jQuery SOAP possible call without prefix in elements but with prefix in method

Tags: jquery, soap

I need to make a SOAP call like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sig="http://anotherNameSpace">
   <soap:Body>
      <a:getCertificate xmlns:a="http://anotherNameSpace">
         <name>John</name>
      </a:getCertificate>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So I've written this javascript code using jQuery SOAP plugin:

```
function soapCall(user, pass){
            $.soap({
                url: "myWdslAddress",
                method: "getCertificate",
                data: {
                    name: user
                },
                namespaceQualifier: "tns",
                namespaceURL: "http://anotherNameSpace",
                noPrefix: true,
                enableLogging: true,
                envAttributes: {
                    'xmlns:sig': 'http://anotherNameSpace'
                },
                HTTPHeaders: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(user + ':' + pass)
                }
            });
        }
```

But it doesnt work because it generates the following request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sig="http://anotherNameSpace">
   <soap:Body>
       <tns:getCertificate xmlns:tns="http://anotherNameSpace">
          <tns:name>John</tns:name>
      </tns:getCertificate>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So I need to remove the "tns" prefix from the "name" element.
I've tried to remove the "namespaceQualifier: "tns" but it removes both from the getCertificate node and in the name node. I need to remove the prefix only from "name" node; getCertificate node have to be with the prefix.

Is is possible to do that?

thanks in advance

Comment: Got the same problem( Have you dealt with it?

Answer (score 2):

I found the following workaround to prepend the namespace to the method only and not its elements.
This is my soap request:

```
$.soap({ /
    url: 'http://webservice',
    method: 'method'
    appendMethodToURL: false,
    data: { mydata },

    namespaceQualifier: 'tns',
    namespaceURL: 'urn:my.namespace',
    noPrefix: true,
    elementName: 'tns:method',

    ...
});
```

The important part is to set `noPrefix: true` and to prepend the namespace hardcoded to the `elementName` which is the same as the method.